# Why Lua has the `<=` opcode and metamethod?

Tags: lua, comparison, operator-overloading

In addition to `==` and `<`, Lua has the `<=` opcode and metamethod (`OP_LE`, `TM_LE`).

Documentation says that

> in the absence of a "le" metamethod, Lua tries the "lt", assuming that a <= b is equivalent to not (b < a)

but why there is '<=' in the first place? Why can't it always use `not (b < a)` for `a <= b`?

**Update:**

If it's all about DSLs, "language hooks", etc, then why Lua doesn't have `~=`, `>`, and `>=` opcodes and metamethods?

Comment: If you define `a <= b` to mean that `a` is a subset of `b`, `not (b < a)` does not imply `a <= b`.

Comment: @Blender, if `<=` is "subset of", what is `<`?

Comment: It's the proper subset (`a` can't be equal to `b`).

Comment: oh @Blender I didn't see that you mentioned this example here already. I made it an answer, but I didn't intend to steal your credit ;)

Comment: @Abyx see my edit which addresses your update

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's implement [sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29). It would be really neat to use the order operators for inclusion tests. `a < b` would mean "`a` is a proper subset of `b`". `a = b` would mena "`a` and `b` are equal". `a <= b` would mean "`a` is a subset of `b`" (not necessarily a proper one, so they might be equal).

Now consider

```
a = Set:new{1, 2, 3}
b = Set:new{"a", "b", "c"}
```

Now neither `a <= b` nor `a < b` is true. Why is that? Because the subset relation only defines a [partial order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_order). The logical assumption that `a <= b` is equivalent to `not(a > b)` is only valid for totally relationships that define a [total order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order).

(Example inspired by "Programming in Lua, 3rd Edition" p. 131)

**EDIT:**

To address your update. Why doesn't have Lua metamethods for `~=`, `>` and `>=` with regards to DSL implementation?

Even on partially ordered sets, the following are always true:

```
a > b    <==>   b < a
a >= b   <==>   b <= a
a ~= b   <==>   not (b == a)
```

Defining different meanings for `<` and `>` (except for switched order) would make your code really confusing, don't you think? Same thing if two `a` and `b` could be both equal and unequal (or neither). I guess, that's why Lua makes the assumption, that it can always implement these three operators in terms of the others.

Comment: no, different meanings for `<` and `>` aren't that confusing. E.g. in C++ `<<` and `>>` mean stream output and input, binary shifts, etc, and nobody complains about it.

Comment: @Abyx but `<<` and `>>` are not expected to be ordering/relational operators. I can't argue here with you about language design decisions like these - I'm not Lua's author. I can only tell you what the situation is, and the above answer is my best guess for why it is like that (and the part before the edit is even confirmed by the author's own book on Lua). if that is not a satisfying answer to your problem, you can always ask on the Lua mailing list. maybe you'll even get an answer from one of the authors.

Answer (score 3):

`not (b < a)` and `a <= b` are not equivalent.

For numbers (i.e. the built-in floating-point type) they give different results in the presence of `NaN`s:

```
a = 0/0
print(a) -- nan
print(a <= a) -- false
print(not(a < a)) -- true
```

If you wanted to define your own BCD or complex number type to behave the same way, you would need to use both metamethods.  You could not get the same effect by defining only `<`.

This does not apply to `a ~= b`, which really *is* equivalent to `not (a == b)`.

```
print(not(a == a)) -- true
print(a ~= a) -- true
```

Comment: yes, a set which includes `NaN` is not totally ordered, if `NaN ~= NaN`. See the answer above.